# Error handling for Macro calling using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python to run excel macros but the problem I am getting is that an error is popping up when I run the macros.

How can hide this error pop up?

Following are the piece of code :

```py
try:
    if os.path.exists("C:\\test.xlsm"):
        # DispatchEx is required in the newest versions of Python.
        excel_macro = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.application")
        excel_path = os.path.expanduser("C:\\test.xlsm")
        workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_path,ReadOnly=1)
        excel_macro.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        excel_macro.Application.Run("Macro1")
        # Save the results in case you have generated data

        workbook.Save()
        excel_macro.Application.Quit()
        del excel_macro
except:
    print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
    excel_macro.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Wrap your call to the macro in a `try/except` block and catch your exception?

Comment: Add it to your question - not to the comments

Comment: I did that but still i am getting pop up. i want to hide this error pop up.